# Como fazer um mapeamento de um coluna de Excel para uma coluna da Base de Dados

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-excel

Eu precisava de ajuda para fazer o mapeamento especifico de uma coluna de um ficheiro excel para uma coluna de uma base de dados.
Eu consigo ler o ficheiro excel mas só não consigo mapear o ficheiro  para a coluna que eu quero na base de dados.
Se precisarem de alguma parte do código basta pedirem como qualquer outra questão.

Queria fazer algo deste género :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer ler o Excel a partir da sua aplicação, ou você quer exportar os dados de um documento excel para uma nova tabela no banco de dados?

Comment: @RafaelMarcos Eu quero ler e depois exportar para um novo banco de dados

Comment: Vc vai ter varios documentos diferentes ou apenas um ?

Comment: Por agora só tenho 2

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que você informou, basta criar as tabelas no Bd e realizar CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete) pela aplicação.

**Exemplo:**
Como você não especificou qual banco está utilizando vou usar o Postgres, mas deve servir pra qualquer um.

Primeiro instale um provedor de dados ADO.NET no projeto, pode ser feito pelo Nuget Manager. Instalei o Npgsql.

Crie o banco pra receber esses dados.

```
CREATE TABLE public."exemplodb"
(
  browse character varying NOT NULL,
  colunadadb1 character varying,
  colunadadb2 character varying,
  colunadadb3 character varying,
  colunadadb4 character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "PK" PRIMARY KEY (browse)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."exemplodb"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Agora ao clicar no botão Enviar BD você programa sua manipulação de dados.

```
        private void enviardbButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("sua connection string aqui"))
            {
                try
                {

                    string commandText = 
                        $"insert into exemplosdb " +
                        $"(browse, colunadadb1, colunadadb2, colunadadb3, colunadadb4) " +
                        $"values ('{browseComboBox.Text}' '{colunadb1ComboBox.Text}', " +
                        $"'{colunadb1ComboBox.Text}', '{colunadb1ComboBox.Text}', '{colunadb1ComboBox.Text}');";
                    int linhasAfetadas = 0;
                    using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        linhasAfetadas = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    if (linhasAfetadas == 1)
                    {
                        //Dados da tela gravados com sucesso.
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Deixando claro que este é um exemplo super simplificado só pra demonstrar! Vários conceitos importantes, como separação de responsábilidades, programação em camadas, entre outros foram ignorados por simplicidade, mas são muito importantes.

Comment: O que eu preciso não é bem isso , acho eu . Eu preciso de ler os nomes das colunas de Excel e mandar para as combobox . Depois se eu quiser que a 3 coluna do Excel insira na primeira coluna da base de dados basta ir à primeira combobox e escolher o nome da coluna de Excel que quero. Não sei se me fiz entender.

Comment: Então vc quer ler o excel, pegar os nomes das colunas e o conteúdo, criar essa coluna no banco armazenando os dados pra depois a aplicação ler desse banco?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil para este caso é usar a ferramenta e importação de dados do SQL Server (Sql Server Import and Export Data) e criar uma nova tabela no banco de dados temporariamente, para que seja possível fazer um insert de novos dados a partir de um select ou um update a partir de um join, para carregar a coluna desejada.